# I don't get any errors but it wont insert the data into the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm doing a registration site and I'm not getting any errors but it wont insert the data into the database

I have tried almost everything but I just can't figure it out

/*The config file is already required I have put it in my header.php file which is automatically required to every file I make so it isn't a config error*/

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["signupbtn"])){
        if (($_POST["firstname"])!= "" && ($_POST["lastname"])!= "" && ($_POST["email"])!= "" && ($_POST["address"])!= "" && ($_POST["city"])!= "" && ($_POST["phone"])!= "") {
            $checkToInsert = $mysqli->query("SELECT id from registrations where email='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["email"])."' AND username='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["username"])."'");
            $row = $checkToInsert->fetch_assoc();
            $count = $checkToInsert->num_rows;
            if($count < 1){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO registrations (firstname, lastname, username, email, password, age, city, address, phone, gender, purpose, hash)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bind_param("ssssiissiiis",  $firstname, $lastname, $username, $email, $password1, $age, $city, $address, $phone, $gender, $purpose, $hash);
                $firstname = $mysqli>real_escape_string($_POST["firstname"]);
                $lastname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["lastname"]);
                $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
                $email =  $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
                $password1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
                $age =  $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["age"]);
                $address = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["address"]);
                $city =  $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["city"]);
                $phone = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["phone"]);
                $gender =  $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["gender"]);
                $purpose =  $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["purpose"]);
                $hash = md5( rand(0,1000) );
                $stmt->execute();
?>

<form action="?page=login" method="POST"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
            <hr>

        <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter firstname" class="form-control" name="firstname" required><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter lastname" name="lastname" required><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" class="form-control" name="username" required><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" class="form-control" name="email" required><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" class="form-control" required><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="age">Age</label>
            <input type="date" placeholder="Enter age" class="form-control" name="age" required><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter address" class="form-control" name="address"><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="city">City</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter city" class="form-control" name="city" required><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter phonenumber" class="form-control" name="phone" required><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="gender">Gender</label><br>
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-label" name="gender" value="0" required> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-label" name="gender" value="1" required> Female<br>
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-label" name="gender" value="2" required> Other<br>
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="purpose">Why are you here?</label><br>
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-label" name="purpose" value="0" required> I want to work<br>
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-label" name="purpose" value="1"required> I'm an employer<br>
  </div><br>
    <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form
```

I want to insert the data to the database

Comment: you probably should add a closing `?>` tag after `$stmt->execute();`.

Comment: Haha its already added but I forgot to copy and paste it on stackoverflow

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php has the prepare first, then the bind, then the assignment, then the execute so the order seems correct...

Comment: Does this typo exist in your local code? `$mysqli>`

Comment: Yes it does exist, but its in the config file

Comment: @MartinZeitler But its the right order if you look here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Any errors being returned by MySQL?

Comment: @Paul070707 you are missing one `?` ...it's 12 question marks, but 12 parameters.

Comment: **I have tried almost everything but I just can't figure it out** no offence but Where is error message ? any log data? perhaps you haven't tried to debug  at all, With Error reporting on no body needs to ask question where problem is kind of typographical

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO registrations (firstname, lastname, username, email, password, age, city, address, phone, gender, purpose, hash) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssiissiiis", $_POST["firstname"], $_POST["lastname"], $_POST["username"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["password"], $_POST["age"], $_POST["city"], $_POST["address"], $_POST["phone"], $_POST["gender"], $_POST["purpose"], md5(rand(0,1000)));
$stmt->execute();
```

`$mysqli->real_escape_string()` is indeed useless in this case, especially when the parameters have already been bound; that is double useless. it only adds some noise to a rather simple script. validating the `$_POST` with `isset()` and `!empty()` is still recommend.

Comment: this is better way to do it, btw what is *double useless* ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя the superlative of useless, while attempting not to use foul language.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables that aren't made so the order of code should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO registrations (firstname, lastname, username, email, password, age, city, address, phone, gender, purpose, hash) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$firstname = $mysqli>real_escape_string($_POST["firstname"]);
$lastname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["lastname"]);
$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$email =  $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$password1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
$age =  $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["age"]);
$address = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["address"]);
$city =  $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["city"]);
$phone = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["phone"]);
$gender =  $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["gender"]);
$purpose =  $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["purpose"]);
$hash = md5( rand(0,1000) );
$stmt->bind_param("ssssiissiiis",  $firstname, $lastname, $username, $email, $password1, $age, $city, $address, $phone, $gender, $purpose, $hash);

$stmt->execute();
```

Also note that `real_escape_string` isn't required when preparing queries. You can however use `(int)` infront of variables that should be an integer. You also might want to check the types `i` or `s` of the variables.

Instead of `($_POST["firstname"])!= ""` you can just use a build in function: `!empty($_POST['firstname'])`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php The first example has them out of order?

Comment: @Paul070707 maybe you can force PHP to show the errors. Put `error_reporting( E_ALL );
 ini_set( 'display_errors', '1' );` somewhere at the top of your script

Comment: @Paul070707 aside from `trying code` i would suggest you try programming defensively, do error checking, logging, looking at the apache and php logs, enabling php error reporting, etc ...

Comment: no need use `real_escape_string` when binding param